# Priority list on sql queries?

Tags: sql

During the interview have faced this question? .  "There is one sql query which has where, having, group by, order by clauses. so when you try to run this query which condition will execute first?  have said: "Where class will be  executed first. " But i want to know the exact order sql queries following. so,

Is Sql is following any Order to execute the queries based on the condition it has? .

If yes Then , Please tell me what is the order?

P>S: Have tried with lot of web resources. But no luck.

Comment: Your question is not bad in itself, but severely lack readability - someone flagged it for Low Quality. Please edit it to be more structured and clean up your punctuation/grammar.

Answer (score 4):

From [SQL Query Order of Operations](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm)

```
1.FROM clause
2.WHERE clause
3.GROUP BY clause
4.HAVING clause
5.SELECT clause
6.ORDER BY clause
```

Comment: Yes, this is a generic answer +1.

Answer (score 3):

The `WHERE` is not comming first. This is the order in mssql:

1. `FROM`
2. `ON`
3. `OUTER`
4. `WHERE`
5. `GROUP BY`
6. `CUBE | ROLLUP`
7. `HAVING`
8. `SELECT`
9. `DISTINCT`
10. `ORDER BY`
11. `TOP`

**Edit**

Talking about the general case. The order of execution is:

1. `FROM`
2. `WHERE`
3. `GROUP BY`
4. `HAVING`
5. `SELECT`
6. `ORDER BY`

Reference:

- [SQL SERVER – Logical Query Processing Phases – Order of Statement
  Execution](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/)
- [SQL Query Order of Operations](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm)

Comment: I don't see OP asking a SQL Server specific answer; rather a generic SQL specific answer.

Comment: In that case, your answer deserve a +1.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the training kit `Querying MS SQL Server 2012`, page 15:
Logical query processing phases:

> ```
> 1. FROM  
> 2. WHERE  
> 3. GROUP BY  
> 4. HAVING  
> 5. SELECT  
> 6. ORDER BY
> ```

Comment: Add reference link if you have so that it will give some more idea or clarification of your answer.

Comment: @Yagnesh, I copied it from a book, and therefore had no link. Will provide one in future answers if I have! :)